# How to know the object name based on memory address in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, cfstring

Hi one of my app is crashing repeatedly and giving below error.

```
 *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1b7a3b70
```

Is there any way to get the object name by using memory address. I used instruments (Zombie) and even i enabled zombies in Xcode but no luck. Can you please help me in this issue i stuck please help me.

Comment: you are releasing one object twice...

Comment: Have you tried adding an exception breakpoint in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Most Objective-C objects don't have names. (There are a few exception, like NSOperationQueue).

It's always a good idea to use the static analyser, to look at all warnings and fix them, etc. Especially if your code uses CoreFoundation which isn't handled automatically by ARC, but the static analyser usually finds incorrect uses.

Showing the stack trace where this happened might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly a string. Likely a CFString but could be bridged from NSString. 
With that knowledge, use the debugger and breakpoints. 
With break points you can step through the code, and use QuickLook to see details about objects.